# Kill the print-r tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

There's a tag on SO: [print-r](/questions/tagged/print-r), which refers to the function `print_r()` in PHP. Currently , 43 out of 46 questions are also tagged [php](/questions/tagged/php) (and one more tagged [php5](/questions/tagged/php5)).

According to the FAQ, a tag that cannot stand alone in a question should not exist, since this tag is dependant on the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag, it should be removed.

I say kill it! Kill it with fire!

Possible?

Comment: Yes. And the `echo` tag to go with it (as long as it's paired with  `php`)

Comment: Could you explain further why this tag is bad?

Comment: @AakashM - should there be a tag for every single PHP function?

Comment: @AakashM edited. But I think woodland already did the explaining.

Comment: [Sending out the signal](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vbLqH.png)... Please hold...

Comment: But that's an argument for renaming it to, I don't know, [tag:php-print-r] or similar, rather than deleting it. And @awoodland the choice isn't between 'none' and 'all'. If there are 40+ questions about this function then why shouldn't there be a tag?

Comment: @AakashM tags for specific parts of an API feels like a case of [can't see the wood for the trees](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/41555/5137) - i.e.  getting caught in in the implementation details and missing the big picture

Comment: Hmm, ok, having done some research I see that `print_r` is actually just a somewhat uninteresting statement (I thought it might be something as exciting as, say, [`ls`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ls) ). Objection withdrawn, although I think I'm still more tag-inclusionist than most people round here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sigh.  We *don't* need a tag for every single function in every single programming language.  Most of the questions in [print-r](/questions/tagged/print-r) are "why does it look like that" and "how do I parse the output."  A few were about using it to assist in debugging.

As such, it's now gone.  I cleaned up some horrible tagging along the way, like adding appropriate debugging tags.

While nuking, I discovered [var-export](/questions/tagged/var-export) and [var-dump](/questions/tagged/var-dump), which has around 46 questions.  I've nuked [var-export](/questions/tagged/var-export), as it only had 4 questions, but I've left [var-dump](/questions/tagged/var-dump) alone when it wasn't paired with [print-r](/questions/tagged/print-r).  It should also be nuked, but that'll be a different discussion.  Most of the questions are probably going to be about debugging (or, worse, parsing output... sigh).