# Kill tag: wordpress-loop

Tags: discussion, tags

I've recently seen the [wordpress-loop](/questions/tagged/wordpress-loop) tag. It has 145 question to date, out of which, **[only 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-loop+-wordpress) don't have the [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) tag**. I suggest we kill this tag, it has no value without the [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress).

Comment: Could become a tag synonym also...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I suggest we kill this tag, it has no value without the [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress).

By the same logic, you'd have to kill [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) because it has no value without [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), and [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) because it has no value without [.net](/questions/tagged/.net). Just because tag A implies tag B doesn't mean that tag A is useless, otherwise we could kill all the tags and just tag everything [programming](/questions/tagged/programming).

The loop is a very important concept in wordpress programming, but not everything about wordpress is necessarily about the loop.

Comment: Not really, the wordpress loop is something very specific to wordpress, **it can't stand alone**, jquery is perfectly capable of standing alone without javascript, mainly because one (sadly) doesn't need to know JavaScript in order to know jQuery. It's not that everything about wordpress is necessarily about the loop, but everything about the loop is necessarily about wordpress.

Comment: "jquery is perfectly capable of standing alone without javascript" That makes no sense. At all. But that aside, what do you say to this sentence: *It's not that everything about programming is necessarily about pointers, but everything about pointers is necessarily about programming.* So should we kill the [pointers] tag?

Comment: Were [programming] a valid tag, than yes, [pointers] would have to be killed. But since [programming] (should) apply to all questions on StackOverflow, we have no such tag.

Comment: Also, please see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122642/kill-the-print-r-tag) similar post. So what, now we should have a tag for every wordpress feature?

Answer (score 0):

Every tag has its own importance, i respect your view. But every tag have its own reason for its making and sometimes tags are also used to clearify the question too.Its up to you which tag you want to choose for your question and which not.

If you don't need any specific tag that doesnot means that others users also don't need it.
And one more thing to say, differnt tags on the same topics are for making things more specific it will tell the users that the question is not only about `wordpress` but also about `wordpress-loop`.

Its about being more specific about your question so there is no reason to delete that tag.

Comment: The [faq] states that if a tag has no standing value, ie if it cannot stand alone in a question, it shouldn't exist. Find me a situation where the wordpress-loop tag can exist without the wordpress tag and I'll remove this question that very moment. You can even look in the questions not tagged as wordpress in the link I provided in the question.

Comment: @Truth  There are so many other tags too which cannot stands alone too, we can take them as a sub-tag but there is no need to delete them.